# Conjugacy in compact Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups

Let $K\subseteq G$ be compact Lie groups, with $G$ connected. Suppose that $H_1,H_2\subseteq K$ are two closed subgroups of $K$ that are conjugate in $G$. Are they conjugate in $K$?

Comment: No. In $G=\operatorname{SO}(3) $ all non-trivial involutions are conjugate. But in $K=\mathfrak{S}_4$, there are two conjugacy classes of non-trivial involutions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general the answer is no. For example, in $U(n)$ you have the subgroup $U(1)^n$ which has many copies of $U(1)$ in (by choosing various "coordinate lines" and act trivially on the orthogonal complement). These specific copies of $U(1)$ are all conjugate in $U(n)$ by permutation matrices, but they are not conjugate in $U(1)^n$ since it is commutative.

Comment: As a tiny matter of language:  by "they [are] all conjugate" you mean of course that the copies that you *specified* are conjugate, not that *all* copies of $\mathrm U(1)$ inside $\mathrm U(1)^n$ are conjugate in $\mathrm U(n)$.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I hope that the current version is more understandable.